# Copying a Time Stamp to a String

Tags: c++

I would like to copy a time stamp to a string **temp**.

```
cout << "Begin time: " << ctime(&timer);
```

Successfully prints out:

Begin time: Mon Mar 3 17:40:04 2014

This is the format that I desire.

My current code; however, compiles, but prints out nothing.

```
sprintf(temp, "Begin time: %d\n", ctime(&timer));
cout << temp << endl;
```

Comment: pretty sure %d means double. ctime() returns a char*. So try %s?

Comment: @RuolinFan Pretty sure `%d` means decimal _integer_. `%lf` is for double.

Comment: Ahh I see, when i said "double" i just meant decimal number. thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the return value of `ctime()` looks like a string, you should write

```
sprintf(temp, "Begin time: %s\n", ctime(&timer));
```

Note the `%s` for string instead of `%d` for decimal integer.

However, to make sure not to overrun the buffer, it would be better to use `ostringstream` and `string`.

```
std::ostringstream strm;
strm << "Begin time: " << ctime(&timer) << "\n";
std::string temp(strm.str());
cout << temp << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could always using `stringstream`, and use it's `str()` member.

```
  stringstream ss;
  ss << "Begin time: " << ctime(&timer);
  cout << ss.str() << endl;
```